# Using Multiple Spring Cloud Gateway Pods on OpenShift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a Spring Cloud Gateway project that is made of multiple smaller projects. We are using Netflix Eureka Server, Spring Cloud Gateway, and multiple microservices. We balance our load on all microservices using the gateway. All of our deployments are running on OpenShift. However, when we scale our Gateway and run multiple pods of it, only one of the gateway pods serves requests and the rest do not receive any requests. How can I load balance the requests across multiple gateway pods?